# Joomla: Custom Template CSS Not Working

Tags: css, joomla

I am currently working on a Joomla site right now with the Vermilion template. I have added my own CSS to the custom CSS file (rt_vemilion-custom.css) but when I save and refresh my page, nothing changes. I have tried editing a variety of different elements on the page in a variety of ways. I have refreshed the cache, tried adding a custom file of my own, tried using class suffixes, and nothing seems to work. For some reason, the CSS shows up in my source code after I refresh the page but the changes are not being made. Any information would be great, I've searched long and hard to no avail.

Joomla V3.64 / 
Gantry V4.1.32 /
Vermilion V1.1

Thanks

Comment: A link to the live website might help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared the Gantry cache? When you make a change in a file which has not been changed so far (in your case, custom.css), you need to clear the Gantry cache. Go to `Extensions > Templates > YOUR_TEMPLATE`. Then click the advanced tab and then click the Clear Cache button and then `Save`. Also, I'd like to suggest you to clear the Joomla! cache as well `System > Delete Cache`. Because Gantry caches its data there too.

After that, clear the browser cache and call the page. It sounds all about caches anyway.